# How can I know which setting TinkerTool is modifying?

Tags: macos, settings

Is there any way to easily know which setting a [TinkerTool](http://bresink.de/osx/TinkerTool.html) option relates to in Mac OS X?

For example, the **Show Hidden and System Files** setting seems to be related to `com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`. What about all the other settings?

Comment: Spotlight search within past (hour, day, minute) for plist files.

Comment: Is this curiosity, or what do you plan to use this information for?

Comment: @DanielL: I originally was wondering because I thought it could help another user based on [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45353/218) I provided. However, I think it could benefit other people if there is a specific setting that TinkerTool fixes for them, but they don't want to have to install the entire product.

Comment: Ah. To try to duplicate its functionality without installing it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Here’s a generic solution to find out what changed after applying a certain setting. I used this to create [my `.osx` file](http://mths.be/osx) which is full of hidden OS X tweaks.

Open Terminal.app, `cd` into a temporary directory, and check the difference between `defaults read` output before and after changing the setting.

```
cd /tmp
defaults read > a
# change the setting using TinkerTool or however you like
defaults read > b
diff a b # view the difference
```

If you’d rather use a UI to view the diffs instead of the `diff` binary, you could download the [Kaleidoscope.app](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) trial.

---

Alternatively, you could do a Spotlight search within the past hour/day/minute for `plist` files. That will only tell you which file changed, though; you would still have to figure out which setting in the file was tweaked.

Comment: Or, you could use [my webapp](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/12/javascript-client-side-diff-tool.html) to see the differences in a GUI.

Comment: Nice tool, @Senseful! There’s another one here: http://kpdecker.github.com/jsdiff/

Answer (score 1):

This may not really be the answer you´re looking for, but I´d suggest having a look at [secrets.blacktree.com](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) for a very good database of hidden OS X settings (they also offer a preference pane to manipulate them).

If you´re looking for a more specific function that is available in TinkerTool, chances are that someone around here will know the command line way for it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The most GUI-friendly way I can think of would be to use the endlessly-fascinating [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart), which lets you see which files on your disk are changing, in real time. With a bit of filtering, you can narrow it down to showing only those files that are changing in your Preferences folders, as you make settings changes in TinkerTool (or anywhere else).

Comment: That app sounds very useful. The link is broken though.

Comment: Link works fine for me in Safari (just tried it again), but you can navigate to the fseventer download from their home page too: http://fernlightning.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you might try:

1) Purchase the paid version of TinkerTool for €11.90. It's called [TinkerTool System 2](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerToolSys2.html).

2) Send an email to the developer, Marcel Bresink. Tell him that you are a paid customer. Ask him nicely if he will tell you the answer to your specific question.

I don't know Marcel, but in my experience, independent shareware software developers are very helpful when you help them out by buying one of their modestly-priced products.