# How to disable the animation for rollout of content when clicking disclosure triangles

Tags: macos, finder, animation

Ever since Mountain Lion, when I select any item in a list (Finder, Xcode) that has sub items and a disclosure triangle (a folder in list view), the items to be displayed rolls down instead of displaying instantly as they were in the past.

I vastly prefer the previous method in Lion and Snow Leopard where the contents were displayed instantly or were hidden instantly.

To see this, open a list view in the Finder and select a folder with contents in it.  Press the right arrow or click the disclosure triangle to display the contents.

**In Mountain Lion, the content rolls down before appearing fully.**

**In Lion and Snow Leopard, this used to be instant, which I greatly prefer.**

From what I have been able to research, this is an NSOutlineView.  What I can't find is the specific property or additional class that does this animation, nor how to stop it.

While Apple goes to extremes to animate everything possible in the interface, all I want is to turn all these useless animations off and get my data displayed as fast as possible… just like in the previous OSes.  Why Apple adds these features and doesn't let us turn them off is beyond me. Is there any NSUserDefault to turn these off?  Preferably systemwide?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45339, but it doesn't have any upvoted answers, so we can't close this question. I have tried to search for preference keys for it with [strings and gdb](http://superuser.com/questions/455755), but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Thanks Lauri. I looked through the header for NSOutlineView and within it is a struct with these two ints, animateExpandAndCollapse and allowAutomaticAnimations, but I can't see any more info on how to turn these off.  I've filed a radar at bugs.apple.com stating they need to declare a public NSUserDefault so that we can disable these "enhancements". It's really, really hard to find any information on this issue, or how to disable it.  I'd appreciate keeping it open so that it can get indexed.  Thanks for turning me on to strings and gdb.